# When adding users to local storage, I can access only the last user, why is that?

Tags: typescript, local-storage, angular16

I am working with angular and I have registration form to add new users. I can add users to local storage but when trying to login, I am only being able to login with the last record in the local storage (the last user).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../model/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserServiceService {

constructor() { }

addUser(user: User) {
  let users = [];
  if(localStorage.getItem('Users')) 
  {
    users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users') as string);
    users = [user, ...[users]];
  } 
  else
  {
    users = [user];
  }
  localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(users))
}

}
```

and in my registration component:

```
onSubmit() {

    this.userSubmitted = true;
    
    if (this.registerationForm.valid)
    {
      if (this.adminPass.value === environment.adminPass){
      this.UserServiceService.addUser(this.userData());
      this.registerationForm.reset();
      this.userSubmitted = false;
      this.alertify.success('You have registered successfully!');
      }
      else{
        this.alertify.error('You need to be an admin! Enter the correct admin password!');
      }
    }
    else{
      this.alertify.error('Please fill all required fields!');
    }
  
  }

  userData(): User{
    return this.user = {
      userName: this.userName.value,
      countrycode: this.countrycode.toString(),
      email: this.email.value,
      password: this.password.value,
      mobile: this.mobile.value
      
    }
  }
```

Comment: `users = [user, ...[users]]` should probably be `users = [user, ...users]` BTW storing your userdatabase in the local storage makes absolutely no sense because 1) it's local to the current machine  2) is insecure as hell

Comment: Thanks that was it. It worked. I know what you mean but I am using this as example as I am learning and exploring at the moment about local storage and json.